# Nginx as loadbalancer for wordpress, error serving static files

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, load-balancing, nginx-upstreams

I'm setting up a simple environment on docker with the following stack:

- nginx as load balance
- wordpress instance
- mysql

My simple docker compose file is the following:

```
nginx:
  build: ../nginx
  links:
    - wordpress:wordpress
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"

wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  ports:
    - "8082:80"
  links:
    - mysqlwp:mysql
  working_dir: /var/www/html
  #volumes:
  #  - wp-content/:/var/www/html/wp-content
  environment:
    WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql
    WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
    WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
mysqlwp:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
    MYSQL_USER: wordpress
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

nginx is built from base image and configuration is the following:

```
upstream wploadbalance{
        least_conn;
        server wordpress;
}

server {
       listen 80;
       server_name my.site.com;
       location / {
           proxy_pass http://wploadbalance;
    }
}
```

Now when I connect to my.site.com I'm correctly redirected to my the wordpress instance but static files are loaded from `http://wploadbalance` which is not accessible.

For example in my browser console I see something like that:

> GET `http://wploadbalance/wp-includes/js/wp-util.min.js?ver=4.4` 
>   net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

As `wploadbalance` is not accessible from outside docker container there should by some way to say to wordpress that static files are serverd from `my.site.com`. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You need to set the WordPress Address (URL) and the Site Address (URL) within the WordPress General Settings. They probably need to be: `http://my.site.com`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

1. Log in to the container:

   `docker exec -it "name_of_container" bash`
2. Add the following lines to wp-config.php

   `define('WP_HOME', 'http://your_domain.com');`

   `define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://your_domain.com');`